# Angular 2 & Typescript: Cannot access class instance from event handler

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular

My use case requires me to add several copies of a child component to a template programmatically (think: iterating through an array with `*ngFor="let childComponent of componentArray"`). The children components all emit a `select` event; the twist is that each of these components has a different event handler within the parent component. Trying to be clever, I decided to store the event handler as a property of each member of `componentArray`. So my template is now something like:

```
<my-cmp *ngFor="let childComponent of componentArray" (select)="childComponent.callback()"></my-cmp>
```

My model contains:

```
componentArray = [{data:0, callback:this.onSelect0}, {data:1, callback:this.onSelect1}];

onSelect0(){/*do stuff specific to childComponent 0*/}
onSelect1(){/*do stuff specific to childComponent 1*/}
```

`callback` is a reference to the class method I would like that particular childComponent's `select` event to trigger.  `callback` is triggered properly; the problem is that from it I cannot access the rest of my component because `this` in that context refers to the `component` during that iteration of the loop.

It sounds more confusing than it is. I've found a workaround but it seems really clunky (I store the class instance as a property in each member of componentArray).  I've made a plunkr accessible from http://plnkr.co/edit/VxxCR8hjUsxQ3SABWe8E?p=preview.  Basically my question is: if I pass the event handler as an object property (`childComponent.callback` above), how can I access my class instance? Any feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's default JS/TS behavior if you pass a method reference directly. You can either use `bind` like `methodName.bind(this)` or a fat arrow function like `() => methodName()` to retain the scope of this.

In your Plunker just change this line

```
  private thing = {name:'ThingOne', onSelect: this.handlerOne };
```

to

```
  private thing = {name:'ThingOne', onSelect:() => this.handlerOne() };
```

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/9NleX9f30dsz76DXDI4l?p=preview)

Comment: Awesome; setting the onSelect property of `thing` to both `onSelect:this.handlerOne.bind(this)` and `onSelect:()=>this.handlerOne()` worked.  Do you prefer one way over the other?

Comment: Definitely `()=>` everywhere

Comment: +1 , this.snapObject.dblclick(() => this.drag(this.snap,this.snapObject));
that's work! thank you..